# Are hotel reservations necessary in Iceland in April?

Tags: bookings, planning, road-trips, iceland

We just decided to visit Iceland April 1-9; that's in 3 weeks, which means we haven't done much planning or organization. We are wondering how practical it will be to improvise once we leave Rejkavik, driving along the loop road and stopping for the night at whatever hotel is convenient when we're tired.

Specifically, how conveniently are hotels located along the road? Are they spaced many hours apart, or can we hope to find one within an hour of deciding it's time? And how likely are they to have available rooms in the beginning of April?

Comment: As the 'season' is just beginning in April, you should't have problems with finding accommodations along the ring road. For your research, [read Cecilia's](https://cile.home.xs4all.nl/) Iceland in April travel blog, with great day-by-day descriptions. Yes, it was 2007, but it's a good reference.

Comment: Iceland's tourist industry has literally exploded in the last 5-6 years. An article from 2007 will be completely useless in judging hotel availability. I would absolutely recommend booking in advance, even in April.

Comment: @Kris why not expand your comment into an answer? Ping me and I will +1 almost surely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what it's worth, we have reserved rooms at hotels along our route, and though rooms were available most places we looked, at least one was booked up and several places indicated that "There are only X rooms left" (where "X" was 2,3, or 4).  Of course, those could simply be canned messages to drive a sense of urgency, but it did suggest that it wouldn't be a good idea to assume there would be rooms readily available.